# searching for the biggest integer in C (more than 2)

Tags: c, search, numbers

How to search for the biggest number, in a set of integers (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)
I code this, contemplating every alternative, except for the == alternatives (longer code!!)
Is there a more efficient, or simpler way to do it, than making an IF satement for every possible solution?
If the number of numbers is bigger? (e.g. 10!!!!)
Thanks.
This is my code

```
if (cat1 > cat2 && cat1> cat3 && cat1>cat4)
    printf("cat 1 is the biggest", cat1);  


if (cat2 > cat1 && cat2> cat3 && cat2>cat4)
    printf("cat 2 is the biggest", cat2) ;  


if (cat3 > cat1 && cat3> cat2 && cat3>cat4)
    printf("cat 3 is the biggest", cat3) ;  


if (cat4 > cat1 && cat4> cat2 && cat4>cat3)
    printf("cat 4 is the biggest", cat4);
```

Comment: Why are you not using an array?

Comment: How about `int cat[4]={...}; int highest=cat[0]; for(i=1;i<4;i++) if (highest<cat[i]) highest=cat[i];` ?

Comment: @mah , why should I ? (asking because I'm learning)

Comment: arrays are much easier to deal with collections of things, versus separate variables. If you examine the solutions people have provided here, you'll see how clean the code to solve this with an array is, and clean code is always better than ugly code. I get the feeling you asked your question because you saw the solution you had would work but was ugly (and not scalable to 10 values, where an array is scalable enough to use all your memory).

Comment: You can do this in one pass with an array. That'd be the best method for you. But for future references, sometimes data like this might be stored in a sorted array. Since the data is guaranteed to be sorted, just return the last value (if you sorted ascending), or the first value (if you sorted descending). Some types of data storage actually are incredibly efficient for large datasets by storing elements in a manner that gives you sorting for free. A [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is one such example.

Comment: Sorry, mabe be I wasn't clear with the question. I could use an array, but I can't sorted it, because is important the index of every number, or in my example, the variable (cat). So what I need, is a way to know th biggest (o the two bigger) values, and the index of each. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straightforward with an array:

```
int data[10] = // ... your ints;
int max = data[0];
for (int i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) 
    if (data[i] > max ) max = data[i];
```

Comment: omg. all answers except for obviously bad one are downvoted ;-)

Comment: Yeah, leaving a comment should be obligatory when downvoting IMO, nut sure it would have helped here though.

Comment: @driis thanks, but what I'm looking for is the following: e.g. three values 5, 8, 6, 8 . The biggest numbers are in index 1 and 3, with the number 8. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array. Here is an example of finding the biggest number of an array of any size.

```
int main(){
  int size,i,biggest;
  int *a = NULL;      

  printf("\nEnter the size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  a = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  printf("\nEnter %d elements in to the array: ”, size);
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);

  // assume the first number is the biggest
  biggest=a[0];

  // iterate on the array and update the biggest number if the current value is bigger than 'biggest'
  for(i=1; i<size; i++){
      if( biggest < a[i])
           biggest=a[i];
  }
  printf("\nYour biggest number is: %d",biggest);

  free(a)
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this function accepts an array and its size as input.

```
int biggest(int *nn,int n) {
    int rv = *nn;
    for(++nn,--n;n;--n,++nn) if(rv<*nn) rv = *nn;
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: I think you mistyped `nnn`as `rv` ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think so. Where?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I'm sure it was a joke about you using `n` and `nn`.

Comment: Not so much a joke in my opinion. Rather, a subtle statement that your variable names _will_ get you into trouble if this is how you do things, and you _will_ spend considerable time debugging a problem that didn't have to exist.

Comment: @mah, it all makes sense when you're talking of considerable amount of code, for the three-lines scope the shorter the code the more reasonable it is. Somehow, my habits haven't got me in this kind of trouble in almost 30 years and even if this changes tomorrow, the percentage of failure would be negligible.

Comment: Even with 3 lines of code and having been problem free for 30 years... typos would be hard to spot (which I'm sure is the root of @Joachim's comment), and if anyone else must read or maintain your code, you aren't doing them any favors. As to tossing around your 30 years of experience -- a) nobody cares how long you've been practicing a good or bad form of developing, b) I've only got 28 years experience but people with only a few years can still set me straight sometimes, and finally, nobody cares how many years of experience I have either except maybe on a job interview.

Comment: I brought in my experience not to claim any authority, but as an input for statistics and never expected anyone to *care*, so the second half of your narration is as much of a cliche as the first part — there's no way in this context for typo to become hard to spot. And to base your hypothesis on @Joachim's comment after he explained that it's a *joke* based on the same general idea sounds very much like a vicious cycle.
And, BTW, "only 28 years" would qualify for "*almost* 30", so even the word as long as "almost" may turn out to be "hard to spot" if one is driven by one's own expectations.

Answer (score 0):

```
int MAX(int a, int b) {
     return a > b ? a : b;
}

// later on...

return MAX(cat1, MAX(cat2, MAX(cat3, cat4)));
```

Comment: Warning, that code is not very efficient at all. Due to macro expansion, it will recompute the MAX-values several times.

Comment: And it does not really easily scale to 10 or 100 numbers.

Comment: If you wanted to do something like this, it'd be easier to write it using a recursive function.

Comment: If you worked for me and you solved the problem this way, you would not work for me any more.

Comment: To illustrate, the above expands into this horrible thing: 
return ((cat1) > ( ((cat2) > ( ((cat3) > ( cat4) ? cat3 :  cat4)) ? cat2 :  ((cat3) > ( cat4) ? cat3 :  cat4))) ? cat1 :  ((cat2) > ( ((cat3) > ( cat4) ? cat3 :  cat4)) ? cat2 :  ((cat3) > ( cat4) ? cat3 :  cat4)));

Comment: @user883617 there are no more MAX computations done than when using arrays -- the inner-most MAX() call would be performed first. The runtime efficiency would actually be better than if using arrays due to no looping but it's truly a horrible solution due to scalability issues (and also maintainability when there are many values to consider).

Comment: @mah I'd have used arrays like everyone else, but (it seems that) the OP doesn't want them

Comment: @mah, no, that is not correct. Look at the expansion generated by the compiler. There are in total 7 greater than comparisons (>), when all you need are 3.

Comment: Actually if you see the OP's question to me, he's asking what the benefit of using them is. Technically your answer is correct because it will work, but (in my opinion) Stack Overflow should do more than just provide a working answer in these cases. (Note however that it was not me that downvoted you.)

Comment: @mah You complain about efficiency. This isn't a job. This is someone learning how to program. Why not explain to him his options? It helps him learn.

Comment: expanding this example to 10 variables give a total of 511 comparisons, compared to 9 using a sane approach (or using a inline function instead of a macro)

Comment: @user883617 yes, I see what you're saying. Shameful on the part of the preprocessor I think.

Comment: @sidran32 do you truly consider this answer to be a positive learning experience for the problem at hand? I consider all answer postings which are not otherwise qualified to be endorsements for the answer containing the right way to solve the problem, and neither this one nor yours is that right way in my opinion.

Comment: @mah _I_ have learned that the C preprocessor isn't what I expected to be at all. Maybe this isn't your case, but me and many others are on SO to _learn_.

Comment: @mah Giving someone the best way to do it doesn't teach him much. Explaining him the various ways to do it, as well as the consequences of doing it that way, do much more to help one learn the concepts.

Comment: @BlackBear -- I'm here to learn as well and thanks to user883617 I learned the preprocessor is not as efficient as I would have expected it to be -- this is also thanks to your answer. While I can appreciate that you may have not liked the tone of my response to you, I would also expect that you learned something about the answer you presented. Had you qualified your answer with something like "this solves the problem but I would not recommend it" I would have never responded to your post. If you want to teach something using ill advised techniques, you need to teach that they're ill advised.