# Search for the biggest number/s in an integer Array in C

Tags: c, search

This continues from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788713/searching-for-the-biggest-integer-in-c-more-than-2).

I have an array, and want to find the biggest numbers in it. But I can't sort then, 'cause is very important indexes of the numbers, so the can't be moved. And finally, the output of my problem should be "the biggest number/s are in index 1 and 4, with the number 8. Here is the array:

```
int anonarray[5] = {3,8,7,5,8};
```

Comment: How are you expecting the result (where the biggest numbers are) to be represented?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the tips.I'll improve day after day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
enum { MAX_ENTRIES = 5 };
int anonarray[MAX_ENTRIES] = { 3, 8, 7, 5, 8 };
int maxval = anonarray[0];
int maxidx[MAX_ENTRIES] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int maxnum = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < MAX_ENTRIES; i++)
{
    if (maxval < anonarray[i])
    {
        /* New largest value - one entry in list */
        maxval = anonarray[i];
        maxnum = 1;
        maxidx[0] = i;
    }
    else if (maxval == anonarray[i])
    {
        /* Another occurrence of current largest value - add entry to list */
        maxidx[maxnum++] = i;
    }
}

printf("The biggest number is in %s", ((maxnum > 1) ? "indices" : "index"));
const char *pad = " ";
for (int i = 0; i < maxnum - 1; i++)
{
    printf("%s%d", pad, maxidx[i]);
    pad = ", ";
}
printf(" %s%d, with value %d.\n", ((maxnum > 1) ? "and " : ""),
       maxidx[maxnum-1], maxval);
```

Note that internationalizing that English-specific formatting will not necessarily be easy!

Comment: I have a question. How do I choose between speed (time consuming loops) or space (big arrays, that I know I wont be using all that space in it). e.g. in this example, you could write more loops, to create the 'maxidx' array just the size it should have.

Comment: It's a standard speed-time (complexity) trade-off. What works best depends on the size of data set you're working with. For up to a few thousand entries, use the space and a single pass through the array. For larger data sets with a wide variety of different values and no really large sets of repeats, you might reduce the size of `maxidx`. If you have really large sets of repeats, then you might use dynamic memory allocation on the `maxidx` array (say allocating 64 values at first, and increasing by doubling that size as necessary). Don't forget that a gigabyte of memory might not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array to find the maximum:

```
int max = a[0], count = 0;

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
  if(max<a[i]) 
     max=a[i]; 

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  if(max==a[i]) 
     count++; //num of maximums
```

Now declare an array to store the indexes:

```
int index[count], j=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 if(a[i]==max)
   index[j++]=i;
}
```

Now `index` has the list of indexes which have the element `max`.

This is asymptically O(n) and tkaes the least possible memory.

Comment: count is NOT how many times the maximum occurs (which your second part depends on); it is how many times your algorithm "changed its mind" about what the maximum is.

Comment: @ScottHunter Good catch! One more loop :)

Comment: You don't need an extra loop; whenever the first sees that max==a[i], increment count; when you change max, reset count.

Comment: That sounds better, still asymptotically the same. Won't be too hard for anyone to modify this!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using the technique of sorting an array of pointers. Something like:

```
int a[5] = {3,8,7,5,8};
int *pa[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pa[i] = &a[i];
}
sort(pa); // pseudocode, be sure to sort by what pa[i] points to
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("n=%d index=%d\n", *pa[i], pa[i] - a);
}
```

Comment: Sorting is a more expensive operation than finding a maximum, even if one has to make a second pass to find all of the locations of the maximum value.

Comment: Why stop there; just assume there's a function that solves the problem and call it.  You've not only provided an algorithm with sub-optimal performance, but hidden the guts of that algorithm in psuedo code.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I would encourage you to provide an alternative answer.

Comment: KingsIndian and JohnathanLeffler beat me to it; neither used an O(n log n) algorithm nor used pseudo code.